# Need help outputting

Tags: python

I’m working on a math quiz and need help outputting

```
Q1: 31 + 11 = **42**            Correct
```

Where 42 is inputted by user and then it outputs correct and incorrect in the same line

```
import random

# setting up variables that i will need

NUMEBR_OF_QUES = 0
count = 0
correctCount = 0
incorrectCount = 0
levelOne = 1
levelTwo = 2
levelThree = 3
addition = 1
subtraction = 2

# Start asking user questions to set up code

quizType = int(input("Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: "))

diffSelection = int(input("Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: "))


# This is if the user chooses addition
while NUMEBR_OF_QUES < 10 and diffSelection == 1 and quizType == 1:
    levOneQues = random.randint(0, 9)
    levOneQuesTwo = random.randint(0, 9)
    NUMEBR_OF_QUES = NUMEBR_OF_QUES + 1
    if quizType == addition and diffSelection == levelOne:
        count = count + 1
        print("Q", count, ": ", levOneQues, " + ", levOneQuesTwo, "=")
        total = int(levOneQues + levOneQuesTwo)
        anwser = int(input())
        
        if anwser == total:
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
            print("Q", count, ": ", levOneQues, " + ", levOneQuesTwo, "= ", anwser, "Correct")
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount + 1
            print("Q", count, ": ", levOneQues, " + ", levOneQuesTwo, "= ", anwser, "Incorrect")
```

For testing purposes, I put 1 for first and whatever for second questions and the output is as follows

```
Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: 1
Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: 3
Q 1 :  278  +  761 =
3
Q 1 :  278  +  761 =  3 Incorrect
```

Comment: I have tried the code, it is correct. Except that, 2 and 3 digit options do not work

Comment: Because the option for 2,3 isn't created @PCM

Comment: @Sujay I know, but option 1 works for me

Comment: Awesome thanks but what about having it all output  in one line instead of it being out outed twice?

Comment: If that s the issue you have gotta check the code

Comment: The only way to do this is to take control of the terminal, using something `termios` or `ncurses`.  With regular input, you can't prevent the user's "enter" key from advancing to the next line.  Neither `termios` nor `ncurses` is particularly hard.

Comment: Wow okay thanks for clarifying I will look into them @TimRoberts

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Been trying things all day nothing works but @PCM Tim was able to clarify

Comment: @pcm have it output just one line

Q1: 31 + 11 = **42**            Correct

Instead of it coming out twice like out putting Q1: 31 + 11= Then I answer and it outputs incorrect or correct in same line like a output input output in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You use too many `if` to restrict the feature.

- `while NUMEBR_OF_QUES < 10 and diffSelection == 1 and quizType == 1`,the `while` loop only enter when you do `add 1-digit`, so the `3-digit` didn't work.
- `if quizType == addition and diffSelection == levelOne:` alse only enter when you do `add 1-digit`.
- try `f-string` instead of print something with comma.
- If you want put everything in one line, maybe `print(chr(27) + "[2J")` and `newline = " "` could help
- If you only want to clear one line, you can use `print ("\033[A                             \033[A")`

#### code:

```
import random
NUMEBR_OF_QUES = 0
count = 0
correctCount = 0
incorrectCount = 0
levelOne = 1
levelTwo = 2
levelThree = 3
addition = 1
subtraction = 2
quizType = int(input("Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: "))
diffSelection = int(input("Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: "))
while NUMEBR_OF_QUES < 10:
    levOneQues = random.randint(0, 10**diffSelection-1)
    levOneQuesTwo = random.randint(0, 10**diffSelection-1)
    NUMEBR_OF_QUES = NUMEBR_OF_QUES + 1
    count = count + 1
    print(f"Q {count} :  {levOneQues}  {'+' if quizType == addition else '-'}  {levOneQuesTwo} =",end =" ")
    total = int(levOneQues + levOneQuesTwo) if quizType == addition else int(levOneQues - levOneQuesTwo)
    anwser = int(input())
    print ("\033[A                             \033[A")
    if anwser == total:
        correctCount = correctCount + 1
        print(f"Q {count} :  {levOneQues}  {'+' if quizType == addition else '-'}  {levOneQuesTwo} = {anwser} Correct")
    else:
        incorrectCount = incorrectCount + 1
        print(f"Q {count} :  {levOneQues}  {'+' if quizType == addition else '-'}  {levOneQuesTwo} = {anwser} Incorrect")
```

#### result:

```
# before press enter
Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: 1
Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: 2
Q 1 :  97  +  22 = 119

# after press enter
Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: 1
Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: 2
Q 1 :  97  +  22 = 119 Correct     
Q 2 :  7  +  99 = 

# before press enter
Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: 2
Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: 2
Q 1 :  50  -  3 = 0
# after press enter
Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: 2
Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: 2
Q 1 :  50  -  3 = 0 Incorrect      
Q 2 :  19  -  8 =
```

Comment: Yes I understand this I only cut some of my code to paste the rest works fine and out puts like yours but I’d like to know if It can out put everything in one line instead of 
Q 2 :  798  -  742 =        
-1
Q 2 :  798  -  742 = Incorrect

Not sure if this is possible

Comment: @bbrichardbb yeah you can do it with `end=" "`, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Okay I been battling this for two days y’all are legends

Comment: I do not think that is what he wants. He wants 'correct' or 'incorrect' next to the input maybe

Comment: @bbrichardbb if my answer help, please accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same output. correct or incorrect should be after user answer but it is technically correct

Comment: I see thanks also if I put answer wrong it changes it to correct but still shows it for me and show s [A    [A   And still seeing the old line

Comment: @bbrichardbb sorry i made a bug, I'll fix it.

Comment: So it still shows [A            A] is it my terminal that just can’t do it

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to print the question? For example could you instead make the input ask the question?

Code:

```
import random

# setting up variables that i will need

NUMEBR_OF_QUES = 0
count = 0
correctCount = 0
incorrectCount = 0
levelOne = 1
levelTwo = 2
levelThree = 3
addition = 1
subtraction = 2

# Start asking user questions to set up code

quizType = int(input("Available quiz type: Enter 1 for addition and 2 for subtraction: "))

diffSelection = int(input("Difficulty Level: Enter 1 for 1-digit, 2 for 2-digit, and 3 for 3-digit: "))


# This is if the user chooses addition
while NUMEBR_OF_QUES < 10 and diffSelection == 1 and quizType == 1:
    levOneQues = random.randint(0, 9)
    levOneQuesTwo = random.randint(0, 9)
    NUMEBR_OF_QUES = NUMEBR_OF_QUES + 1
    if quizType == addition and diffSelection == levelOne:
        count = count + 1
        total = int(levOneQues + levOneQuesTwo)
        answer = int (input ("Q " + str(count) + " : " + str(levOneQues) + " + " + str(levOneQuesTwo) + " = "))
        
        if anwser == total:
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
            print("Q", count, ": ", levOneQues, " + ", levOneQuesTwo, "= ", anwser, "Correct")
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount + 1
            print("Q", count, ": ", levOneQues, " + ", levOneQuesTwo, "= ", anwser, "Incorrect")
```

This would only post to the terminal after the answer is provided so it includes the correct or incorrect tag.

Comment: Out puts twice 
Q 1 : 5 + 4 = 9
Q 1 :  5  +  4 =  9 Correct

Comment: Ahh, I've tested this with the interactive window in anaconda, it doesn't seem to work with a normal terminal, I'll see if I can find something else

Comment: I knew it it was my terminal cause I’m on Pythonista on iPad. Once I get home ill try to use pycharm terminal with your code